# A newcommand (for typesetting the symbol for parallel lines) not compiled

Tags: math-mode

I copied the following command from a post on this web site.

```
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}
```

I have used it in other code and it has typeset the symbol for parallel lines nicely.  Why is it not compiled in this code?  (I try to use it in the last sentence.  I put a `%` in front of it so that the code will compile.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,backgrounds,patterns}


\usepackage{graphicx,tipa}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tipa}
%This command typesets an arc symbol over letters.
\newcommand{\arc}[1]{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{#1}%
  \ooalign{\resizebox{\wd9}{\height}{\texttoptiebar{\phantom{A}}}\cr#1}}
%This command has LaTeX typeset the symbol for parallel lines.
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}


\begin{document}

\noindent {\textbf{Proposition}} \vskip1.25mm
{\em $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ are chords in a circle that do not intersect. They are parallel if, and only if, $\arc{AC} = \arc{BD}$.}
\vskip0.2in

\noindent {\textbf{Demonstration}} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ are chords in a circle centered at $O$. $\arc{AC} = \arc{BD}$ if, and only if, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOC} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BOD}$.
\begin{equation*}
{\mathrm{m}}\angle{ABC} = \frac{1}{2} \, {\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOC}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
{\mathrm{m}}\angle{BCD} = \frac{1}{2} \, {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BOD} .
\end{equation*}
So, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{AOC} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BOD}$ if, and only if, ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{ABC} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BCD}$. $\angle{ABC}$ and $\angle{BCD}$ are alternate interior angles. ${\mathrm{m}}\angle{ABC} = {\mathrm{m}}\angle{BCD}$ if, and only if, 
%$\overline{AB} \parallelsum \overline{CD}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: am i correct that you want a "slanted parallel"?  the `\!` that begins and ends the expansion of your definition is a backspace, which is meaningless (never mind invalid) at the beginning of a `\mathbin` object.  so if you just remove those two `!`s, there will be no complaints, but i'm not sure whether the result is what you want.

Comment: @barbara beeton  Yes, the command should typeset two slanted, parallel lines.

Comment: that symbol is defined in unicode as `U+2AFD` so it should be in the stix / xits fonts, possible with the command name `\sslant`.

Answer (score 6):

If you load `tipa` with the `safe` option, the commands

```
\: \; \! \* \|
```

will not be redefined. Without it, you still have some aliases available, because `tipa.sty` does

```
\let\tipamedspace\:
\let\tipathickspace\;
\let\tipanegthinspace\!
\let\tipasterisktmp\*
\let\tipapipetmp\|
```

so you can do

```
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{%
  \mathbin{\tipanegthinspace/\mkern-5mu/\tipanegthinspace}%
}
```

On the other hand, you can get the best of both worlds by fixing the wrong approach made by `tipa`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tipa}

\UndeclareTextCommand{\!}{T3}
\DeclareTextCommand{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{}
\DeclareTextAccentDefault{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}
\DeclareTextComposite{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{G}{201}
\DeclareTextComposite{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{b}{225}
\DeclareTextComposite{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{d}{226}
\DeclareTextComposite{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{g}{228}
\DeclareTextComposite{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{j}{234}
\DeclareTextComposite{\tipaEXCLAM}{T3}{o}{242}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\!}{%
  \ifmmode\mskip-\thinmuskip\else\expandafter\tipaEXCLAM\fi
}

\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}

\begin{document}

\textipa{\!G \!b \!d \!g \!j \!o}

$AB \parallelsum CD$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`tipa` seems to redefine `\!` into something other than a negative mathspace:

```
 \DeclareTextCommand{\!}{T3}[1]{#1}
```

so it trips up your definition. You could write

```
\mskip -\thinmuskip
```

instead of your two `\!`s (that is the original definition of `\!`), but as Barbara points out, they shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Yes, that is what Werner has said.  Can I just include a command `\hspace{-2pt}` or something like that in the `\newcommand`?  What is the "length" of `\!`?

Comment: @user74973: you can literally write `\mskip -\thinmuskip` instead of `\!`, `thinmuskip` is the length you're looking for.

Comment: Are you saying that `\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\mskip -\thinmuskip\mkern-5mu\mskip -\thinmuskip}}` gives the same pair of slanted lines as what I had if `tipa` was not in the preamble?

Comment: @egreg  Why did you remove your post?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an interaction with loading [`tipa`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tipa).

Using `\mathbin{<stuff>}` forces a specific amount of space around `<stuff>`, so it really doesn't make sense to include spacing adjustments like `\!`. Instead, and similar to what you're already doing using `\mkern` for adjustments *outside* of `\mathbin`, if needed at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tipa}

%This command has LaTeX typeset the symbol for parallel lines.
%\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{/\mkern-5mu/}}

\begin{document}

$AB \parallelsum CD$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would the `\!` in the `\newcommand` have been ignored by `LaTeX` if `tipa` had not been in the preamble?  Your `\newcommand{\parallelsum}` has too much extra space between `AB` and the slanted parallel lines and between the slanted parallel lines and `CD`.

Comment: @user74973: Yes. You might as well use `\newcommand{\parallelsum}{/\mkern-5mu/}` only.

Comment: OK.  What does the `/` before and after `\mkern-5mu` do?