# Closer slanted parallel symbol

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, symbols

Looking the @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272072/a-newcommand-for-typesetting-the-symbol-for-parallel-lines-not-compiled) where I have deleted some parts of code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\parallelsum}{\mathbin{\!/\mkern-5mu/\!}}
\begin{document}
$AB \parallelsum CD$
\end{document}
```

I would to change the classical symbol of `\parallel`

[image]

to obtain another same symbol of parallel

[image]

where the slanted should not be above and below the two red lines, are closer to each other and are in line with the text, in mathematical mode in both subscript and overscript mode. If there's already a symbol like this I'm searching for even better for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Raise and scale.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newparallel}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\new@parallel\relax}}
\newcommand{\new@parallel}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1T$}% get the height of an uppercase letter
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1/\mkern-5mu/$}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$AB\newparallel CD$

$\scriptstyle AB\newparallel CD$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation with `picture` mode. One can easily vary the slope by acting on the second argument to `\mathpalette`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newparallel}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\new@parallel{0.3}}}
\newcommand{\new@parallel}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settoheight{\unitlength}{$#1T$}% get the height of an uppercase letter
  \sbox\z@{\new@parallel@slash{#1}{#2}}%
  \mkern0.5mu\copy\z@\mkern-0.5mu\copy\z@\mkern0.5mu
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\new@parallel@slash}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(#2,1)
  \roundcap
  \new@parallel@linethickness{#1}
  \Line(0,0)(#2,1)
  \end{picture}%
}
\newcommand{\new@parallel@linethickness}[1]{%
  \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle \fontdimen8\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle \fontdimen8\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle \fontdimen8\scriptfont\else
      1.1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$AB\newparallel CD$ ${\newparallel}/$

$\scriptstyle AB\newparallel CD$ $\scriptstyle{\newparallel}/$

$\scriptscriptstyle AB\newparallel CD$ $\scriptscriptstyle{\newparallel}/$

{\Large$AB\newparallel CD$ ${\newparallel}/$}

\end{document}
```

This is for Computer Modern fonts; for different fonts, `\roundcap` might be omitted. In the example I show the standard slash to compare the line thickness.

[image]

Comment: Always my infinite...."grazie di cuore". But if you put this simbol as subscript `_` or as exponent is the same the measure?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to keep the aspect of the symbol, and also increase the line widths back to normal?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Possibly. No time now: with `pict2e` it should be possible.

Comment: @Sebastiano The symbol scales correctly in subscripts/superscripts. I added a different implementation.

Comment: @egreg Impressive your work. Using newtxtext as text which code should I use the second maybe? Always thank you.

Comment: I've a problem with those solutions in ```\section``` environment. Try ``` \section{Decomposition of $F_\newparallel$}```. (sorry for update. Better to post another question ?)

Comment: @Piroooh For single occurrence, use `\protect\newparallel`; if you need it in several section titles or captions, replace `\newcommand{\newparallel}` with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\newparallel}`. Anyway it should be `F_{\newparallel}` (don't forget the braces).

Comment: @egreg Solved with ```\DeclareRobustCommand``` The second problem was about brackets over command. Thanks for the so fast answer :-) !

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `stmaryrd`  and `\clipbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\mysslash}{\mathrel{\mkern-5mu\clipbox{0 0.75ex 0 0}{${\sslash}$}\!}}

\begin{document}

$ AB\mysslash CD $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `$\scriptstyle AB\mysslash CD $`.

Comment: It's of course designed for \display or \textstyle. For the other cases, one should recompute the clipping and use `\mathpalette`.

Comment: may you provide a code for the symbol not parallel based on your symbol for parallel ?